# ReactiveForm using NgFor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm stuck. My approach seems inefficient and incorrect.

What I am doing is, generating my form values using *ngFor, I am dynamically creating form controls for Answer's as well as questions.

The issue is that, on Submit I need to have the answers associated with the questions, so I can pass to the next screen. The questions generated from the *ngFor are sorted by checkbox selected, if the selected = true; then bubble the question to the top.

The issue is that on submit, pvqForm passed the formControls, I need to associate the answer with the question it was associated with. FormControls have a prefix {{i}} --> index, however, this index is after the sort. So Index 19 may not be question_id = '19'.

The Object I am trying to achieve onSubmit is:

```
{
   question_id: "#",
   EN: "Question - #",
   FR: "Question - #",
   answer: "",
   isSelected: true
}
```

I can save all the questions within an array, and simply use question_id to match the questions. However, how can I achieve the matching question_id along with the answer together?

The object that begins the *ngFor is in the shape of...

```
{
  question_id: "1",
  EN: "Question 1 - EN",
  FR: "Question 1 - FR",
  isSelected: true
},
{ 
  question_id: "2",
  EN: "Question 2 - EN",
  FR: "Question 2 - FR",
  isSelected: false
}
```

My Component:

```
export class FpPVQ implements OnInit {
  private questions: any;
  private lang: string;
  private counter: number = 0;
  private checkedLimit: number = 5;
  private updateMode: boolean = false;
  private createMode: boolean = false;
  private deadlinePassed: boolean = false;
  private previousScreen: string = "";
  private flowA: boolean = false;
  private flowB: boolean = false;
  private flowC: boolean = false;
  private flowD: boolean = false;
  private pvqForm: FormGroup;
  private answer_0: FormControl;
  private answer_1: FormControl;
  private answer_2: FormControl;
  private answer_3: FormControl;
  private answer_4: FormControl;
  private answer_5: FormControl;
  private answer_6: FormControl;
  private answer_7: FormControl;
  private answer_8: FormControl;
  private answer_9: FormControl;
  private answer_10: FormControl;
  private answer_11: FormControl;
  private answer_12: FormControl;
  private answer_13: FormControl;
  private answer_14: FormControl;
  private answer_15: FormControl;
  private answer_16: FormControl;
  private answer_17: FormControl;
  private answer_18: FormControl;
  private answer_19: FormControl;
  private question_0: FormControl;
  private question_1: FormControl;
  private question_2: FormControl;
  private question_3: FormControl;
  private question_4: FormControl;
  private question_5: FormControl;
  private question_6: FormControl;
  private question_7: FormControl;
  private question_8: FormControl;
  private question_9: FormControl;
  private question_10: FormControl;
  private question_11: FormControl;
  private question_12: FormControl;
  private question_13: FormControl;
  private question_14: FormControl;
  private question_15: FormControl;
  private question_16: FormControl;
  private question_17: FormControl;
  private question_18: FormControl;
  private question_19: FormControl;


  private answerControlArr: Array<FormControl> = [];
  private questionsArr: Array<any> = [];



@ViewChild(DirtyModalComponent) public readonly dirtyModal: DirtyModalComponent;

  constructor(private _pvqStepUp: PVQStepUpService, private _langToggle: ErrorToggleService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lang = window['appdata'].apiUserLanguage;
    console.log('fpPVQ:: pvqStepUpData --> {}, ', this._pvqStepUp.data);
    if (this._pvqStepUp.data != null) {
      this.previousScreen = this._pvqStepUp.data.previousScreen;
      this.questions = this._pvqStepUp.data.pvqs;
      console.log('4176 FPVQ:: flow --> {}', this._pvqStepUp.data.flow);
      switch(this._pvqStepUp.data.flow){
        case "A": this.flowA = true; break;
        case "B": this.flowB = true; break;
        case "C": this.flowC = true; break;
        case "D": this.flowD = true; break;
      }
      this.questions.forEach(object => {
        this.questionsArr.push([object.question_EN, object.question_FR, object.answer]);
        console.log(object.question_id, object.EN, object.FR);
      })
      if (this._pvqStepUp.data.deadlinePassed)
        this.deadlinePassed = true;
    }

this.answer_0 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_1 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_2 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_3 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_4 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_5 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_6 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_7 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_8 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_9 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_10 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_11 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_12 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_13 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_14 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_15 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_16 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_17 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_18 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.answer_19 = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

this.question_0 = new FormControl();
this.question_1 = new FormControl();
this.question_2 = new FormControl();
this.question_3 = new FormControl();
this.question_4 = new FormControl();
this.question_5 = new FormControl();
this.question_6 = new FormControl();
this.question_7 = new FormControl();
this.question_8 = new FormControl();
this.question_9 = new FormControl();
this.question_10 = new FormControl();
this.question_11 = new FormControl();
this.question_12 = new FormControl();
this.question_13 = new FormControl();
this.question_14 = new FormControl();
this.question_15 = new FormControl();
this.question_16 = new FormControl();
this.question_17 = new FormControl();
this.question_18 = new FormControl();
this.question_19 = new FormControl();

this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_0);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_1);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_2);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_3);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_4);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_5);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_6);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_7);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_8);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_9);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_10);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_11);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_12);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_13);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_14);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_15);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_16);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_17);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_18);
this.answerControlArr.push(this.answer_19);

this.pvqForm = new FormGroup({
  answerControl0: this.answer_0,
  answerControl1: this.answer_1,
  answerControl2: this.answer_2,
  answerControl3: this.answer_3,
  answerControl4: this.answer_4,
  answerControl5: this.answer_5,
  answerControl6: this.answer_6,
  answerControl7: this.answer_7,
  answerControl8: this.answer_8,
  answerControl9: this.answer_9,
  answerControl10: this.answer_10,
  answerControl11: this.answer_11,
  answerControl12: this.answer_12,
  answerControl13: this.answer_13,
  answerControl14: this.answer_14,
  answerControl15: this.answer_15,
  answerControl16: this.answer_16,
  answerControl17: this.answer_17,
  answerControl18: this.answer_18,
  answerControl19: this.answer_19,
  questionControl0: this.question_0,
  questionControl1: this.question_1,
  questionControl2: this.question_2,
  questionControl3: this.question_3,
  questionControl4: this.question_4,
  questionControl5: this.question_5,
  questionControl6: this.question_6,
  questionControl7: this.question_7,
  questionControl8: this.question_8,
  questionControl9: this.question_9,
  questionControl10: this.question_10,
  questionControl11: this.question_11,
  questionControl12: this.question_12,
  questionControl13: this.question_13,
  questionControl14: this.question_14,
  questionControl15: this.question_15,
  questionControl16: this.question_16,
  questionControl17: this.question_17,
  questionControl18: this.question_18,
  questionControl19: this.question_19
});

    //Determine if Update or Create
    if (this._pvqStepUp.data.flow !== 'A' && this._pvqStepUp.data.flow != "B") {
      this.createMode = true;
      this.counter = 0;
    } else {
      this.updateMode = true;
      this.counter = 5;
    }

    this._langToggle.getLanguage().subscribe(
      lang => {
        this.lang = lang.toString();
      });
  }


  checkedState(event, checkBox) {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      if (this.counter < this.checkedLimit) {
        this.counter++;
      } else {
        event.target.checked = false;
      }
    } else if (this.counter > 0) {
      let index = event.target.name;
      //When clicking off the checkbox, set value to null
      this.answerControlArr[index].setValue(null);
      this.counter--;
    }
  }

  onSubmit(pvqForm: any) {
    console.log('4176-21 Submitted data --> {}', pvqForm);
    // console.log(pvqForm._value);
    Object.keys(pvqForm._value).map((key) => {
      console.log('4176-21 Object Key: ', key, ' Object Value: ', pvqForm._value[key]);
      // console.log('Question Controm name ' + pvqForm._value[key]);
      if(key.startsWith('questionControl')){
      }
      if(key.startsWith('answerControl')){
        let index = key.replace('answerControl', '');
        console.log('Index is: ' + index);
        console.log('Value is: ', pvqForm._value[key]);
      }
    })
  }

  cancel() {
    this.dirtyModal.show();
  }

  modalStay() {
    this.dirtyModal.hide();
  }

  modalLeave() {
    //Navigate Away to the previous screen
    // this.router.navigate([this.previousScreen]);
    location.assign(this.previousScreen);
  }

  isDisabled() {
    if (this.counter == 5) {
      //Enable if 5 Checkboxes are selected
      return false;
    } else {
      //Disable if 5 Checkboxes are not selected
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

The HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="pvqForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(pvqForm)" novalidate>
      <div *ngFor="let question of questions | sortBy: 'selected'; let i = index" class="row container-generic">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="container-input-checkbox">
            <label class="container-flex">
            <input formControlName='questionControl{{i}}' #checkBox class="pvq-create-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="{{i}}" (change)="checkedState($event, checkBox)" [checked]="question.selected"> 
            <div class="pvq-create-label">
              <div *ngIf="lang == 'en'">
                  <p aria-label="English Question">{{ question.EN }}</p>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="lang == 'fr'">
                  <p aria-label="French Question">{{ question.FR }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
            <label [@hideShow]="checkBox.checked ? 'show' : 'hide'">Answer
            <input minlength=4 formControlName='answerControl{{i}}' type="textbox" name="{{i}}">
             <div *ngIf="!pvqForm.controls['answerControl' + i].valid && pvqForm.controls['answerControl' + i].touched" style="color: red;">
               Error here 
             </div>
          </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove a lot of your duplication using [Form Arrays](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

These can be created using the [Form Builder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder)

I have also grouped question and answers together.

```js
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.questionGroups = this.fb.array(this.getQuestions().map(question => this.fb.group(question)));

  this.pvqForm = this.fb.group({
    questions: this.questionGroups
  });

  console.log(this.pvqForm);
}

getQuestions() {
  const questionControlArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    questionControlArray.push({ 
      question: ['', Validators.required], 
      answer: ['']
    });
  }
  return questionControlArray;
}
```

Then they would be displayed in the view something like:

```html
<form [formGroup]="pvqForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(pvqForm)">
  <div [formArrayName]="'questions'">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questionGroups.controls; let i = index;" class="form-group">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <label class="center-block">{{'question ' + i}}:
          <input formControlName="question" class="form-control"/> 
        </label>
        <label class="center-block">{{'answer ' + i}}:
          <input formControlName="answer" class="form-control"> 
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isnt what i was looking for. Maybe I could use form arrays to my advtange and come up with a solution. Until then, still lost.

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to associate questions with answers and can't because the order is changing but the IDs aren't is that right? Could you post an image of what the component looks like? I'm afraid there were too many missing dependencies for me to create the component myself

Comment: Yeah, if there is a way to group the question or id of the question with the answer, that way I can find out what answer has been completed by the user for the corresponding question. The ngFor index is just an index for the amiunt of questions in thebarray, when sorted the question Id is not equivalent to the index. I have posted thr component code. I can pist screen shots later on when i am home.

Comment: You could create form groups that contain one answer and one question, then display those form groups with the `*ngFor` that way the question and answer will be grouped together in the response.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, not sure how thr submitted form would look like. I have to try when I am home.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer to include how to do that. There is also a git repo [here](https://github.com/0mpurdy/stack-overflow) where I have committed the code I used to test this

Comment: Hey I solved it my own way, thanks for all your help -- I have a new problem now :) 

What I did was instead of answerControl{{i}} I changed it to answerControl{{question.questionId}}, then I looped through the forms controls and replaced all answerControl with "", and retrieved the id. Then took the id and looped through the questions array and matched the id, to retrieve the question associated with the answer.